# Apple permission hell: osascript and Accessibility (Assistive Access)

Tags: macos, applescript, permission-denied

Apple permission hell: osascript and Accessibility (Assistive Access).

Error: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)

I have a one line script in a file called QuickenUpdate.scpt

Run in Script Editor (works):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Quicken" to click menu item "Update all Online Accounts" of menu "Accounts" of menu bar item "Accounts" of menu bar 1
```

Run in Terminal (works):

```
/usr/bin/osascript /Deployment/bin/Stocks-1.01.03/scripts/QuickenUpdate.scpt
```

I have a shell script (QU.sh) to run this.

```
#!/bin/bash
. ~/.bashrc
/usr/bin/osascript /Deployment/bin/Stocks-1.01.03/scripts/QuickenUpdate.scpt 2>&1
exit 0
```

If I run QU.sh from inside BBEdit, it works.

If I run QU.sh from Terminal, it works.

If I try to run this via launchd, it fails with: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-1719).

launchd plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>Sec_Stocks_QuickenUpdate.job</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/Deployment/bin/Stocks-1.01.03/bin/QU.sh</string>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>9</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>45</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You cannot add osascript to assistive access as it is not an app!

The extremely frustrating thing is that I did get it to work a few weeks ago, but cannot remember how.

I had to make some changes to the project and redeploy it (it is part of a larger project that gets built and deployed using an ANT script).

The fact that you have to jump through hoops to get a new build to work is ridiculous.

How on earth does one get this permission hell sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error...

To use ‘System Events’ to control an application (eg: Quicken), the shell script and the target application both need to be in the Privacy/Accessibility list in System Preferences. The shell script cannot be added manually.

Add the target App manually in System Preferences. Keep the list open, then run the shell script via launchd (I use the ‘Launch Control’ app to run the job).

The job will fail, but the shell script should now be in the Accessibility list. Check it (turn it on) and then the script should execute OK.